# Wordpress posts in google search showing mixed http and https

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, web, seo

Recently i have moved my domain to https but in google search posts showing both http and https affecting SEO and when i search site:newkannada.com showing my other domain content..

my htaccess content

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options -MultiViews
RedirectMatch 301 ^/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/([a-z0-9\-/]+) https://newkannada.com/$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ $1.html [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any help ?

Thanks in Advance
[website in google search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYScz.png)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO, not programming. SEO questions may be asked on [Webmasters.SE](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. google takes time to understand your site has migrate to https, so in the end you jest need to wait a little bit
2. you have to force https, why http://www.newkannada.com/ is not redirecting to https://www.newkannada.com/? There are some wordpress plugin you can use it
3. after redirecting is ok you can register your site (http and https versions) on the google search console and send https sitemap for google.

Good stuff 4 you here: https://www.keycdn.com/blog/http-to-https/